# Is device token is same for all app in Android?

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, devicetoken

In case of Apple, device token is same for all apps in device. It just differentiate it with certificate.
But what in case of android? Is device token for all apps is same or different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Google Cloud Messaging device tokens (or more accurate Registration IDs or Registration Tokens) are different for each app on the same device.

BTW, even though I haven't tested it myself, I read that iOS device tokens are also different for each app on the same device starting in iOS7.

Comment: @nilesh I can answer for sure only for Android, though I added a sentence regarding iOS.

Answer (score 0):

In ios for every app the device token is different. But for one app in the ios for single device is same for every time.

But in android the device token are taken from google and if the device is registered then that id is provided else new device id is returned.